# Reversal Point and Tangent line

Tags: analysis

Given is the function $\frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3+2x$, the task is to find the the turning points and then the tangent line to the left-most turning point.

Deriving the functin we get $x^3 -3x^2 + 2x$ and with $x^3 -3x^2 + 2x = (x-1)(x^2-2x-2)$ the solutions to $(x-1)(x^2-2x-2) = 0$ are $x_1 =1$, $x_2 = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $x_3 = 1 - \sqrt{3}$. The leftmost turning point is $x_3$.
Regarding the tangentline at this point: As far as I understand, the slope of the tangent corresponds to the slope of the original function at this point, which would be zero here since at a minima the function has slope zero.
Is hence the equation for tangent simply $-1 = 0*(1-\sqrt{3})-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent line has slope $0$, so has equation of shape $y=c$. To find the value of $c$, substitute $1-\sqrt{3}$ in the expression for our function. If we want to simplify, it is a relatively messy process, since we are substituting into a degree $4$ polynomial.

**Remark:** Ther is a typo in the OP, $x^3-3x^2+2$ was intended. But that is what you actually worked with, so the calculations are correct. Things only break down at the end, at the equation of tangent line phase.

Comment: Hi! Not sure..so I did in fact substituted $1 - \sqrt{3}$, and hence I just got c = -1 since as you also mention the slope is 0. So how is then my equation wrong? :-) thank you

Comment: Your equation has no $y$ in it.

Comment: I see, sorry. So then y = -1 would be the tangent.

Comment: Yes, that's the tangent line. (I checked the correctness of the substitution.)